# Italicization of mathematical symbols: quantity symbols vs units symbols

Tags: mathematics, writing, formatting

The SI conventions state that variables and quantity symbols should be italicized, while unit symbols should be roman (see, e.g., [this useful reference/cheat sheet](https://www.periodni.com/download/rules_and_style_conventions_for_writing_si_units.pdf)).  For example,

[image]

Here the proton mass (m_p) is being used as a quantity.  But you could use the same quantity as a unit, in which case should you use a roman font?  For example,

[image]

Or is it really that **SI** units specifically should be in roman font, and everything else should be italicized?

Comment: I guess SI also specifies which are the valid unit symbols. Otherwise, I can just claim that I'm using an unit symbol called "mile" which is equal to 1609.344 m, and I'm perfectly compliant with SI.

Comment: Note, however, that in the first equation the subscript "p" should be upright because it's not a quantity or a numerical value but stands for _proton_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general approach (see e.g. [NIST](https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/pdf/typefaces.pdf) or [IUPAC](https://iupac.org/cms/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/ICTNS-On-the-use-of-italic-and-roman-fonts-for-symbols-in-scientific-text.pdf) for sources) is to consider physical constants, such as the proton mass, as quantities. They are thus usually italicized, even when used as units.

Certain units, notably the electronvolt (eV) and the atomic mass unit (u), are considered so important that they are "accepted for use with the SI system", see the [SI brochure](https://www.bipm.org/en/publications/si-brochure/table7.html). These should be given in roman type.